# Windows audio to keep speaker from sleeping

Tags: windows, audio

I started using a portable speaker for my Windows computer, and after discovering it goes to sleep got the following explanation from the manufacturer:

> That model, as well as the rest of our portable speakers, has a power-saving feature wherein it will automatically enter the Standby mode after it detects no audio or no actions received for 10 minutes. And there are no options to disable the power saving/sleep mode.

So I want a script or program that will play an inaudible tone (e.g., over 30kHz) at least every 10 minutes.  But the tone has to be low-volume, or fade in and out, to avoid making the speaker click when it starts.

Comment: Notice that a 30 kHz tone may result in a audible tone when sampled at 44 or 48 kHz due to some audio theorems.

Comment: White noise might be an alternative.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I tested a simple `[System.Console]::Beep(30000,1000)` and I could not hear it.  So that will be fine for me.

Comment: 30 kHz and byproducts might also be filtered out almost completely. I've used 25 Hz with up/down ramp in the past for speaker line testing. Wave file can be prepared in audacity (and this would be most flexible) and this seems like just few lines of code in basically any language (few dozen more if BT speaker is not a default audio device and thus device selection is needed). Maybe even combination of Windows Task Scheduler + sox + wave file. Are you looking for something sitting in tray or something completely invisible (say, process started by autostart without any kind of UI)?

Comment: @TMSZ – creating a .WAV in Audacity is a good idea.  As is the idea of a simple script that is called by a scheduled task.

Comment: You'd probably do better with 30Hz than 30KHz. your speakers won't be able to reproduce either, but at least 30Hz is likely inside the hardware's repro spec [even if only in theory]

Comment: @Tetsujin I would have thought so, but I tested [System.Console]::Beep(30,1000) and the speaker made an audible hum – probably not producing a 30Hz tone, but making noise while trying!

Comment: I don't understand the 'code'. Is that 30Hz at full volume? If so, you're probably generating massive distortion harmonics, which is what you actually hear. You really need **darn** good speakers to repro 30Hz

Comment: I looked it up - freq:duration. I also noticed the lowest value is 37 so it should error 'out of range' at 30. Anyway, a system beep is not the way to test this.